# Using Koa Routes with Heroku returns 404 errors

Tags: heroku, next.js, koa

I am building my first Shopify public app and used their Next.js and React example to get started. I needed to create an API and couldn't route it with Next.js so I added Koa and Koa-Routes to map it.

It works well locally and I'm able to post and get information from my database using the API. When I deploy it on Heroku, these Koa routes do not work anymore and return 404 errors.

server.js (only the relevant bits)

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
var bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const next = require('next');
const routes = require('./routes')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = new Koa();
    const router = new Router();
    server.use(bodyParser());
    server.use(session(server));
    server.keys = [SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY];

    require('./routes/api')(router);

    ...
```

./routes/api

```
const SettingsControllers = require('../controller/settings');

module.exports = function(router){

    router.get('/api/settings/:shop', SettingsControllers.find);
    router.put('/api/settings', SettingsControllers.save);

    return router

}
```

Here is the message I get on API calls

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/settings/13msdev.myshopify.com" host=app.website.com request_id=12345 fwd="12.12.12.12.12" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=2020 protocol=https
```